# GCP Cloud Run Logs in Grafana

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grafana, google-cloud-run

Is there an easy way to export GCP cloud run logs to Grafana Cloud in anyway?

Perhaps with loki or another exporter tool to output to Grafana...or?

I can't find any guides which even go over this logging exporting process.

Answer (score 1):

GCP Cloud Run logs are sent to GCP Cloud Logging. So, how to get Cloud Logging into Grafana. [Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/gcplog-cloud/) shows:

> 1. Pull-based subscription: Promtail pulls log entries from a GCP PubSub topic
> 2. Push-based subscription: GCP sends log entries to a web server that Promtail listens

The outline of the basic steps is:

> - Roles and Permission
> - Setup Pubsub Topic
> - Setup Log Router
> - Grant log sink the pubsub publisher role
> - Create Pubsub subscription for Grafana Loki
> - Pull
> - Push
> - ServiceAccount for Promtail
> - Operations

Comment: I believe this only works with a grafana server in the stack, which I don't have. There is no promtail endpoint url otherwise that I can see running only grafana cloud.